# Powershell Pipeline Processing - $_ Works but $ParamName Does Not

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I'm having trouble understanding this behavior...

Given a Powershell script like this (updated with actual code)...

```
[cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Default")]
param (
    [cmdletbinding()]

    [Parameter( Mandatory=$true, 
                ValueFromPipeline = $true,
                ParameterSetName="Default")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Azure")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="AWS")]                
    [Alias("Server")]
    [String[]] $SqlServer,

    # other parameters
)

BEGIN {} 
PROCESS {


    <# *************************************
    PROCESS EACH SERVER IN THE PIPELINE
    **************************************** #>
    Write-Debug "Processing SQL server $_..."
        # GET SMO OBJECTS
    $Error.Clear()
    try {
        # GET CONNECTION TO TARGET SERVER
        $_svr = _get-sqlconnection -Server $_ -Login $DatabaseLogin -Pwd $Password

        # PROCESS DATABASES ON SERVER
    } catch {

        $Error

    }
} END {}
```

It is my understanding that $_ is the current object in the pipeline and I think I understand why "Write-Host $_" works.  But why does "Write-Host $InputVariable" output an empty string?

How must I define the parameter so I can pass values both through the pipeline and as a named parameter (i.e. - ./script.ps -InputVariable "something")?

This works:           "someservername" | ./script
This does not work:   ./script -SqlServer "someservername"

Thank you.

Comment: The code provided does not run as is.

Comment: Please fix the issues in the `param` block (`[cmdletbinding]` -> `[cmdletbinding()]`, `Paramter` -> `Parameter`) and let us know 1) which version of PowerShell you're seeing this behavior in and 2) what input you're passing to the script :)

Comment: After making the fixes that @MathiasR.Jessen mentioned, the code works as intended. I.e. both `Write-Host $_` _and_ `Write-Host $InputVariable` output non-empty strings when provided non-empty input.

Comment: @bprocket What is the actual code you're running? I have a sense that the example you provided here is substantially different than the code in which you're observing the issue.

Comment: Code example is updated.  I'm trying not to be too verbose in the code example.  Let me know if it helps.

Comment: your code does not have a pipeline ... so where is the `$_` supposed to come from?

Answer (score 3):

`$_` is only populated when working on pipeline input.

If you want to accept both:

```
"string","morestrings" | ./script.ps1
# and
./script.ps1 -MyParameter "string","morestrings"
```

... then use the following pattern:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [string[]]$MyParameter
)

process {
    foreach($paramValue in $MyParameter){
        Write-Host "MyParameter: $paramValue"
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `"string","morestrings" | ./script.ps1 -myparameter { $_ }` :).